# pregmatch or substr best for removing unknown number of characters from string and leaving only last two

Tags: php

Is it best with PHP7+ to use `preg_match` or `substr` methods for removing unknown number of characters from the start of a string. Eg New York, NY. I am stripping the city and only need the last two characters.

Comment: Regexes have more overhead. Use `substr()`.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: And much more straightforward `substr($string, -2);` will return the last 2 regardless of what the other ones are or how many.